# Did Daniel LaRusso really join Cobra Kai?

Tags: plot-explanation, karate-kid, cobra-kai

In season two of [Cobra Kai](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt7221388/), Daniel tells his Miyagi-Do students that he knows that Cobra Kai students can change because he was once Cobra Kai.

That is news to me, but he tells the story which includes flash back scenes of Ralph Macchio as a Cobra Kai.

> Cobra Kai sells power, strength, and when I joined, I was Well, I was weak.
>   It was 1985. I had just won my first All Valley, and Mr. Miyagi didn't want me to compete anymore. He never really liked the idea of fighting for trophies in the first place. So, he and I, we got into this big argument, and what did I do? I joined Cobra Kai.
>
> I learned to strike first, strike hard, show no mercy, and it turned me into an angry and violent kid. It changed me.
>
> It's not something I'm proud of... But my point is, anyone can be seduced by Cobra Kai, even me. And I'll admit, Cobra Kai makes you feel stronger, tougher, but it will also get you in trouble.
>
> And that's what happened to me.
>
> I'm just lucky Mr. Miyagi was willing to take me back.

The scenes shown are of a younger Ralph Macchio in a dojo with another instructor kicking dummies with faces taped on them and then at a party punching some other kid in the face.

The other thing that confuses me about this story is this happened after he won his first All Valley, which is the end of the first movie. Isn't that when Cobra Kai ended? That is when Sensei Reese broke Johnny's trophy and all his students started to leave him right? So did Cobra Kai continue after Sensei Reese's meltdown?

I honestly don't remember any of this from the original movies. So, is this new information or am I forgetting something from those movies? And where did that old footage come from?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I honestly don't remember any of this from the original movies.

Haven't you seen [The Karate Kid Part III](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0097647/)? Of course you are forgetting something.

> So did Cobra Kai continue after Sensei Reese's meltdown?

Former sensei of Cobra Kai dojo, John Kreese, visits his Vietnam War comrade, Terry Silver, a wealthy businessman who founded the Cobra Kai and now owns a toxic-waste disposal business. Silver vows to personally help him get revenge on Daniel and Mr. Miyagi and re-establish the Cobra Kai, sending Kreese on vacation to Tahiti to rest and recuperate. [Source: Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Karate_Kid_Part_III)

I haven't seen Cobra Kai but I know which scene you are referring to.

It's Daniel getting trained by Terry Silver after Mr. Miyagi refuses to teach him because Daniel wanted to defend his title. Only when Mr. Migayi learns that Kreese and Terry had planned a revenge on Daniel, he agrees to teach him.

Comment: I have not seen it. I actually thought that one was about a girl.

Comment: @sanpaco: You mean [this one](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0110657/)?

Comment: Yep that's the one. Looks like I have been mixed up for years haha. I'll have to checkout KK3! Thanks for setting me straight.

Answer (score 1):

The scenes are from *Karate Kid III* and Daniel isn't saying he ACTUALLY joined Cobra Kai, which did end after the first movie. He's saying he sort of went the "Cobra Kai" direction with a teacher who was akin to Kreese and the antithesis of Miyagi because of their falling out.

So he's saying he became a Cobra Kai in spirit not literally.